# Installation of Icinga on Linux server

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios

We have already setup Nagios Server and its working fine.We want to setup the ICINGA as Monitoring tool.IS it right decision?

IS it same as Nagios?
Can you please provide us the steps to install Icinga on Linux server?
Does it support to API to all the service from other web application or mobile.
??

Please help

Answer (score 3):

We have Icinga1 and Icinga2 as our monitoring system.

> Icinga1: It is a fork of Nagios
>   Icinga2: In this nagios is re-written from scratch

For Installation of Icinga1 on Ubuntu 14.04, refer to [this](https://openmoz.wordpress.com/2015/01/07/installing-icinga-monitoring-tool-on-ubuntu/) link, it is explained over here.

Here Is the step by step procedure for installing Icinga2

**Step 1: **Add repository and install icinga2 on both host and monitoring server

```
#add-apt-repository ppa:formorer/icinga
#apt-get update
#apt-get install icinga2
```

**Step 2: **Install MySQL database on Monitoring Server

```
#apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

**Step 3: **Install Icinga2 Database

```
#apt-get install icinga2-ido-mysql
```

**Step 4: ** Login to Mysql Database

```
#mysql -u root -p
```

**Step 5: **Now create a database named 'icinga' and assign privileges to it. For that run following in mysql shell

```
CREATE DATABASE icinga;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, CREATE VIEW, INDEX, EXECUTE ON icinga.* TO 'icinga'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'icinga';
quit
```

**Step 6: **Enable livestatus feature

```
#icinga2 feature enable livestatus
```

**Step 7: **Restart Icinga

```
#   service icinga2 restart
```

**Step 8: **Assign User mode
   usermod -a -G nagios www-data

**Step 9: **Enable some features

```
#icinga2 feature enable compatlog
#icinga2 feature enable ido-mysql
#icinga2 feature enable command
#service icinga2 restart
```

For installing Web View, go through this process
**Step 1: ** Install Git

```
#apt-get install git
```

**Step 2: ** Clone web view repository

```
#git clone git://git.icinga.org/icingaweb2.git
```

**Step 3: **Move cloned directory to /usr/share/icingaweb

```
#mv ../icingaweb2 /usr/share/icingaweb
```

**Step 4: **Navigate to /usr/share/icingaweb

```
#cd /usr/share/icingaweb
```

**Step 5: **Install Lamp Server

```
#apt-get install tasksel
#apt-get install lamp-server
```

**Step 6: **Configure apache with icinga

```
./bin/icingacli setup config webserver apache --document-root /usr/share/icingaweb/public
```

**Step 8: **Above command will generate a apache configuration code, copy the code generated code and add this directory to be listen at port 80 in configuration file. You can make a new configuration file and activate that file using `a2ensites` command or add the code to 000-default.conf file

**Step 9: **restart apache
    #a2enmod rewrite
    #service apache2 restart

**Step 10: **Create a directory in which icinga web will keep all of its authentication files

```
#mkdir /etc/icingaweb2
```

**Step 11: **Shange its permission to 777

```
#chmod 777 -R /etc/icingaweb
```

**Step 12: **Now open your favorite Browser and navigate to localhost/icingaweb2/setup
its asking for setup token, generate it by follwing command.

```
#su www-data --shell=/bin/bash -c "mkdir -m 2770 /etc/icingaweb2; head -c 12 /dev/urandom | base64 | tee /etc/icingaweb2/setup.token; chmod 0660 /etc/icingaweb2/setup.token;";
```

**You are done, you are ready for monitoring. Just resolve some packages dependencies of php5 and setup your monitoring server**

For further reference go through [Official Documentation](http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/getting-started#getting-started)

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Which should I use Icinga1 and Icinga2 ?  

Also Please provide me the steps to install on LINUX server not on Ubuntu...plz

Comment: I will prefer icina2. Which LINUX flavor are you using? As only syntax are changed but procedure is same for any linux distribution. Even you can go through the Official Getting Started Link that I have provided at the end of aforementioned answer.

Comment: What are the difference of Icinga1 and Icinga2  ? WE are using Centos...Please provide me the steps to install on Centos

Comment: In a simple words Icinga1 is old one and Icinga2 in the latest version with Improved UX/UI. https://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/ . This link will provide the answer of your all questions. Go through offical documentation once. And as I have mentioned earlier the process is same for setting up Icinga on any Linux Flavor, the only difference is of packages, which you can find in mentioned link.

Comment: ok...thanks..

Could you please provide us the steps to install Icinga 2 on Centsos??

Comment: Will you please do me a favor by navigating to this link once please. http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/